# Laravel unix timegaps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, unix-timestamp

```
id------dj_id------from-------------------to-------------

1-------2---------1485961200---------1485964800

2-------4---------1485968400---------1485972000

3-------3---------1486058400---------1486065600
```

I'm using Laravel to help a friend with a radio website of his.
The above table is the "shows" table, and is displayed at the website (upcoming shows list etc.).
But I've encountered a problem. 
When there is no current show playing, we want to display a "Jukebox" banner. 
Between show 2 and 3 from the table, there is a time gap of 24 hours where there are no shows, and we try 
to get a solution where we just can do a true / false check if there are no more current shows, and then display some Jukebox data where there is no shows playing.

The code I've come up with is this:

```
   <div class="shows">

    {{-- This is the jukebox, if there are no shows in the database table, or there are no upcoming shows, we want to show this --}}
    @if (count($shows) == 0 || $show_jukebox == true)

        <div class="current_dj">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('img/jukebox.png') }}">
            <p class="onair_now">On-Air now</p>
            <p class="dj_name">Jukebox</p>
        </div>

    @endif

    {{-- Show the current show --}}
    @foreach($shows as $show)

        @if ($show -> to > \Carbon\Carbon::now() -> format('U') && $show -> from < \Carbon\Carbon::now() -> format('U'))

            <div class="current_dj">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('banners/' . $show -> dj -> banner) }}">
                <p class="onair_now">On-Air now</p>
                <p class="dj_name">{{ $show -> dj -> name }}</p>
            </div>

        @endif

    @endforeach

    {{-- Show a --}}
    @foreach($shows as $show)

        @if ($show -> to > \Carbon\Carbon::now() -> format('U') && $show -> from > \Carbon\Carbon::now() -> format('U') )

            <div class="show">

                <p class="showname">{{ $show -> dj -> name }}</p>
                <p class="timestamp">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('U', $show -> from)  -> format('H:i') }} - {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('U', $show -> to)  -> format('H:i') }}</p>
                <a href="#" class="more">Les mer...</a>

            </div>

        @endif

    @endforeach

    </div>
```

And this is how i "try" to check if I should show the jukebox banner or not.
But that clearly does not work.

```
$now = Carbon::now() -> format('U');
$shows = Show::get();
$show_jukebox = false;
foreach($shows as $show) {
    if ($show -> from > $now && $show -> to > $now) {
        $show_jukebox = true;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say "But that clearly does not work.", what does that mean exactly? What's happening that shouldn't be? Is the problem in your view, or in the code checking for a current show?

Comment: In the code checking for a current show something is wrong. Beucase when a show ends, and there is no more shows for some time, the jukebox wont show up. It shows no banners or anything.